# How to add to an ember blueprint's renamedFiles property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

An ember blueprint has a static property called [renamedFiles](https://ember-cli.com/api/files/lib_models_blueprint.js.html#l1356) that by default renames `gitignore` from the files folder to `.gitignore` in the target folder.

The question is, how can I extend this list?

So far I tried these in the `index.js` of my blueprint, but they don't seem to work:

```
module.exports = {

  renamedFiles: {
    'something': 'somethingElse'
  },

  beforeInstall: function() {
    this._super.renamedFiles = {
      'something': 'somethingElse',
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`renamedFiles` is a static property. You can access it via `this.constructor.renamedFiles` in `beforeInstall` hook. You can also modify it. Since this is a static propery, the modification may have some side-effects.

The correct way to modify the file name is to use [`fileMapTokens` hook](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Blueprint.html#method_fileMapTokens). You don't need to manipulate `renamedFiles`.

Here is a code sample:

```
fileMapTokens(){
  return {
    something(){
      return 'somethingElse';
    },
    'my-funcy-file-name': function(){
      return 'myfuncyfilename';
    }
  };
}
```